# simpleSamlPHP isAuthenticated always returning false

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, simplesamlphp

I just started developing with simplesamlPHP. I installed simpleSamlPhp and I followed the steps given in  https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/development/simplesamlphp-sp-api to integrate my php application with simpleSAMLPhp and I am using the simpleSaml APIs given in the document.

Below is the code:

```
require_once('/var/simplesamlphp/lib/_autoload.php');
$auth = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple('default-sp');
if($auth->isAuthenticated()){
  $attributes = $auth->getAttributes();
}else{
  echo "Not authenticated";
  $auth->requireAuth();
}
```

$auth->isAuthenticated() is always returning false. Do I need to do anything else? or am I missing something?

Comment: Assuming you've configured everything properly (identity provider, etc), this is pretty much all you need to do you your application. Configure debug logging in SimpleSAML and see what's happening when you try to authenticate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling `isAuthenticated()`, you need to call `requireAuth()`. The idea is that you request authentication against an entity and later on you are able to check if the user is authenticated or not.

```
require_once('/var/simplesamlphp/lib/_autoload.php');
$auth = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple('default-sp');
$auth->requireAuth();
if($auth->isAuthenticated()){
   $attributes = $auth->getAttributes();
}else{
   echo "Not authenticated";
}
```